# send wav file in HTTP POST request(using mongoose embedded web server)

Tags: web-services, http, mongoose-web-server

I Am trying to send Wav file using mongoose http server. Basically,I am forming POST request and sending with 
struct mg_connection *mg_connect_http(struct mg_mgr *mgr,
                                      mg_event_handler_t ev_handler,
                                      const char *url,
                                      const char *extra_headers,
                                      const char *post_data) 
API,This API expect const char *post_data in visible ascii string format but my wav file is raw data, as there are 0x00(null) characters in raw wav file , whole content of file is not sent. Is there any conversation I need to perform on wav file before I send it to server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try chunked encoding.
I.e. you should not send raw data in `mg_connect_http`, but use `mg_send_http_chunk` and Co.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you might try is:

```
c = mg_connect();
mg_set_protocol_http_websocket(c);
mg_printf(c, "POST /my_uri HTTP/1.0\r\n");
mg_printf(c, "Content-Length: %lu\r\n\r\n", (unsigned long) post_len);
mg_send(c, post, post_len);
```

Note this will buffer the whole WAV file in memory before sending.